# I can't access my website

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, website

24 hours ago I registered my domain www.mojgolub.com
Everyone else beside me can access it, but only I can't. I don't understand why.

My other domain which I registered yesterday I could access just in few minutes. It's driving me crazy, what could be the problem.

I tried to flush dns, to renew IP to reset router,ccleared cache, cookies, used different browsers...

Comment: That happened to me once, I cleared my browser cache and it worked.

Comment: What do you mean by can't access it - what error messages are you seeing and where are they ?

Comment: no error messages, it just shows me some random website

Comment: what operating system r u on?

Comment: Windows XP Service Pack 3

Comment: can you open up terminal and do: nslookup www.mojgolub.com and post results here?

Comment: Server:  ns2.bnet.hr
Address:  83.139.104.2



Non-authoritative answer:

Name:    www.mojgolub.com
Address:  66.96.162.128

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your DNS - ns2.bnet.hr resolves to a wrong IP address for that domain. You can try changing your DNS to something like http://www.opendns.com/ (see their DNS ips on their site) or to 8.8.8.8 which I think is Google's public DNS. Those resolve the domain name to correct IP which is this:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 www.mojgolub.com 

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.mojgolub.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44403
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.mojgolub.com.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.mojgolub.com.   13155   IN  CNAME   mojgolub.com.
mojgolub.com.       13155   IN  A   **85.10.49.66**

;; Query time: 53 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 14 15:04:06 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 64
```

Here is how to change DNS settings: http://www.mediacollege.com/computer/network/dns.html